# SharedElement Trans. Between Fragment doesn't work with .add() works only with .replace()

Tags: android, android-fragments, shared-element-transition

Im using SharedElement Transition between two fragments. It works fine with .replace(), however if I use .add() the transition doesn't work. Am I missing something?

onItemClickListener that starts the new frag.

```
urlSetter(list.get(position).getId());
TextView image = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.teamID);

newFragment = new TeamsActivity();
Bundle args = new Bundle();

FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    args.putString("TRNS", image.getTransitionName());
    newFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(R.transition.trans_move));
    newFragment.setEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.explode));
    setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.slide_top));
    setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.no_transition));
    transaction.addSharedElement(image, image.getTransitionName());
}
args.putInt("LOGO", mTeamLogos[list.get(position).getId()].getDrawableId());
args.putString("CLUB", list.get(position).getName2());
args.putString("URL", url);
args.putInt("POSITION", position);
newFragment.setArguments(args);

transaction.addToBackStack("xyz");
transaction.add(R.id.frame_layout, newFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" are you getting an error?

Comment: I mean the Transition itself doesn't work, if I use replace method it slides from outscreen to top and slide down on back. if I use .add() there is no transition working

Comment: Transitions aren't my strong suite, but shouldn't you be calling `setSharedElementEnterTransition` on `getWindow()`? I could be completely wrong but you are setting the exit transition differently.

Comment: Refer the same problem...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029886/shared-element-transition-not-working-on-add-fragment-in-android?noredirect=1#comment71691121_36029886