# Shared element transition not working on add fragment in android

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I have observed that shared element transition only works with "replace" method. Is there any way by which this can also work with "add" method

Comment: "add" method adds another fragment on top of current fragment, so there is actually no transition happening.

Comment: Even i am facing the same problem...Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @AkshayMahajan as described by Devanshu, "add" method adds fragment on top of another fragment so there is no transition happens.

Comment: @RHL is there any workaround, so that i don't have to replace the first fragment (where i am doing heavy work like retrieving data from database) and still get the shared element transition ?

Comment: @AkshayMahajan do the data retrieval/heavy task on activity or some where else outside fragment and replace the fragment.